# UIAlertView crashes when button tapped: how to solve?

Tags: ios, crash, uialertview, exc-bad-access, uialertviewdelegate

I have a class that I instance to show an alert view like this:

```
- (void)showAlert
{       
  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you want to try again?"
                                                        message:nil
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];

  [alertView show];
}
```

}

I need `self` to be the delegate because I need `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` to be called to perform some actions when the user taps the alert view's button. This usually works well, but from time to time, I get this crash:

```
SIGSEGV
UIKit-[UIAlertView(Private) modalItem:shouldDismissForButtonAtIndex:]
```

I guess this is because the delegate, for any reason, was released, right? Or is this because what was released was the alert view? How could I solve this? I need the alert view to have a delegate, and I've reading several related posts and I couldn't find an answer that fits my scenario.

I'm testing in iOS 7.0, I don`t know if that could have to do with the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check if you are calling the alertview in the main thread?

Comment: You can check it with `[NSThread isMainThread]`

Comment: I always create the object that shows the alert view within a view controller. It is a strong property. Can I assume it is always called in the main thread, then? Unfortunately I don't know how to cause this crash intentionally

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana if I check `[NSThread isMainThread]` before showing the alert view, will I prevent the app from reaching this crash?

Comment: @AppsDev `[NSThread isMainThread]` is only to check if you are in the main thread. IS to check @Rose comment.

Comment: please check    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ alertView show] });

Comment: @Rose I'm using TestFlight and the crash report says it is the `Primary Thread Thread 0`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you tap alert when its delegate is released:

```
delegate:self
```

It happens because UIAlertView delegate property is of assign type (not weak!).
So your delegate potentially can point to released object.

Solution:

in dealloc method you need to clear delegate for your alertView

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    _alertView.delegate = nil;
}
```

But before you need to make iVar _alertView and use it for your alertViews

```
- (void)showAlert
{       
     _alertView = ...;

     [_alertView show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as follows:

```
- (void)showAlert {       
  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you want to try again?"
                                                        message:nil
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];

  [alertView show];
}
```

Its due to you are missing the `nil` for `otherButtonTitles` part.

**Missing sentinel in method dispatch** warning will be shown if you didn't add `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, my fault... I actually have `nil` added but it seems I removed it from the code I pasted here, sorry. I'm going to edit it.

Comment: Is that still crashing?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the alertView's delegate object released while clicking the button. I think it's a bug of SDK:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/ delegate;    // weak reference
```

should be:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/ delegate;    // weak reference
```

To fix the issue:

1. add a weak delegate for UIAlertView using association.
2. swizzle the init, setDelegate: delegate methods, set alertView delegate to self, set step 1 weak delegate with the param delegate.
3. implement all delegate methods, deliver the methods using the weak delegate.